# Uso da tag section no HTML5

Tags: html5, semântica

Muito se fala sobre semântica no HTML5 e suas novas tags, a minha duvida é, quando se deve utilizar a tag `<section>` de uma forma semanticamente correta? Existe alguma regra/critério/escopo para o uso da mesma?

Comment: Oi Alex! Dá uma olhada a essa outra pergunta e respostas. Se achares que não são duplicadas avisa.